# How to enable/emulate hardware virtualization for the Acer Aspire 5738?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, acer-aspire, windows-95

I want to emulate Windows 95 from Windows 7 on my Acer Aspire 5738. I've downloaded Windows Virtual PC, but creating a new virtual machine gives:

> Windows Virtual PC cannot start because this computer does not support hardware-assisted virtualization.

How can I enable HAV? I can't find an appropriate option in the boot menu.

Is there any way to do this with just software virtualization? I could take the performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU does not support hardware virtualization.  If it did, you would turn it on or off in the BIOS.

From [Intel's page about that CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/37255/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6600-(2M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)):

> Advanced Technologies
>
> - Intel® Turbo Boost Technology: No
> - Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology: No
> - **Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x): No**
> - Intel® Trusted Execution Technology: No
> - Intel® 64: Yes
> - Enhanced Intel SpeedStep® Technology: Yes
> - Intel® Demand Based Switching: No
> - Execute Disable Bit: Yes

Answer (score 0):

You can download an [update to run Windows Virtual PC without hardware virtualization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/windows-virtual-pc-no-hardware-virtualization-update-now-available-for-download). Supposedly only XP is supported.

You might be better support, including integration, with an older version of Virtual PC, or with another product like VirtualBox.